# Get two different state when using React.useState()

Tags: reactjs

**set state:**

```
  const [token, setToken] = React.useState("");
```

**change state:**

```
  const calculate = () => {
    setToken(() =>(`name:${uuid()}`)); //_______________________________________P
    console.log('in calculate: '+ token)  // ___________________________________A
    commitMutation({
      variables: {
        input: {
          token, //_____________________________________________________________B
        },
      }
    });
  };
```

**use state:**

```
<div className={css(styles.updatedTime)}>
              <Button
                disabled={isMutationInFlight}
                kind="blank"
                intent="basic"
                onClick={() => {
                  calculate();
                }}
              >
                calculate
              </Button>
            <TestToaster token={token}/>  //___________________________________C
</div>
```

After press calculate button, the token could be reset in `P`. I hope the token would be same in `A, B, C`. But `A` and `B` are same, `C` is different. It seems the token in `A` and `B` is slower than `C`. How could I make `A,B,C` same? Thanks!

Comment: setState does not change the state immediately, but only in the next render!

Comment: Save UUID to a variable first

Comment: Yes, he's a right state does not update immediately. If you want to do immediate action, then use variables.

Comment: It helps me to understand the principle, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is because state changes are async, so token will change after calculate is finished and not during the execution(Thats why A and B show you prev state).

```
const calculate = () => {
const newToken = `name:${uuid()}`
setToken(newToken); //_______________________________________P
console.log('in calculate: '+ newToken)  // ___________________________________A
commitMutation({
  variables: {
    input: {
      newToken, //_____________________________________________________________B
    },
  }
});
};
```

This should work and won't affect your code.